# cordova datepicker plugin not working in iOS8: UITableView dataSource is not set

Tags: uitableview, cordova, datepicker, ios8, uidatepicker

after updated to iOS8, the cordova datepicker plugin not work. it crashed with following message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'

but i don't see any UITableView related code in the plugin source code. i don't know, maybe there is an internal UITableView in the UIDatePicker?

here is the code(i remove some non-relative code for easy reading):

```
- (UIPopoverController *)createPopover:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {

  UIView *datePickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerViewWidth, pickerViewHeight)];

  if(!self.datePicker){
    self.datePicker = [self createDatePicker:options frame:frame];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  }

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [self createISODateFormatter:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" timezone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
  NSString *dateString = [options objectForKey:@"date"];
  self.datePicker.date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];// if remove this line, it works fine

  [datePickerView addSubview:self.datePicker];

  UIViewController *datePickerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
  datePickerViewController.view = datePickerView;

  UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:datePickerViewController];
  popover.delegate = self;
  [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(pickerViewWidth, pickerViewHeight) animated:NO];

  [popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor inView:self.webView.superview  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];   

  return popover;
}
```

this line:

```
self.datePicker.date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

finally leads to crash, and with debug, i found the value of dateString is:

2014-10-17T10:0:00Z

2014-10-17T20:0:00Z

and it crash from second display, the first time is always ok

could you please give me some clue? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally i find out the issue:

the source code of cordova DatePicker, reuse the UIDatePicker instance:

```
if(!self.datePicker){
    self.datePicker = [self createDatePicker];
    [self.datePicker addTarget];
}
```

and, it works fine in iOS7, but lead to crash in iOS8.

in iOS8, don't share UIDatePicker instance in multi UIView, so i modify the code to:

```
// in iOS8, UIDatePicker couldn't be shared in multi UIViews, it will cause crash. so   create new UIDatePicker instance every time
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {

    self.datePicker = [self createDatePicker:options frame:frame];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}else{

    if(!self.datePicker){
        self.datePicker = [self createDatePicker:options frame:frame];
        [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
```

hope this can help someone like me

Comment: Is this the plugin you used? https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: exactly. several issues about this problem there

Comment: Your code didn't fix the problem on the latest version of that plugin, which version did you use?

Comment: I have a pull request pending for this plugin that fixes this. In the meantime you can use my fork here: https://github.com/Jayco-Design/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: This isn't limited to Cordova. I had the same problem with a regular native app on iOS 9. In my case I had a view with a UIDatePicker that is shown in a popover view controller. Creating a new UIDatePicker instance every time I need to show it solved my problem.